# How to include jar with source code in war with Maven build

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven multimodule project, then I want to pack source code of one of modules into jar and add it to war (same module or another one) in WEB-INF/lib path.

Then, I tried to use Maven Source Plugin, like this:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>       
      <attach>true</attach>
    </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Then add it as normal dependency, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>myModuleName</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Problem is that, when I'm running build with simple command line

> mvn clean install

I've got error with information that he cannot find my artifact with source code. It's looks like Maven first looks for dependency and later builds it.

How to configure it in correct way?

Comment: you want to add directly classes in the lib folder ?? It is not conventional.

Comment: I want to pack classes in jar and attach it into war inside WEB-INF/lib folder. I've got some reason to do this.

Comment: Your need is conventional. It should work without additional task.
Can you show the pom.xml of your war, the pom parent of the modules and all the stacktrace ?

Comment: Do you really need the the source package in your lib folder of a web project ? This does not make sense...

Answer (score 1):

Source package into a war file does not make sense. Using maven-source-plugin it is better the goal `jar-no-fork`if you need to have that in only one module...

Furthermore if you like to have the classes in the in your war module as a jar file in the lib folder the simplest solution is to use the configuration of the maven-war-plugin:

```xml
<configuration>
  <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
</configuration>
```

This will result in creating a jar file out of the class in `src/main/java`.